# Saving multiple values using HTML5 local Storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a page that utilises local storage to hold the amount of times a button is clicked:

```
function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "" + localStorage.clickcount + ".";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}
```

I now want to add 3 more buttons and want to store the values for each of these separately. To display it I know I would refer to the appropriate ID but I'm not sure how to store these values. I imagine that I will have 3 further functions that will perform this and need to create a variable for each of the values? Am i on the correct path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you can do the following to store items in `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.firstButtonCount += 1;

localStorage.secondButtonCount +=1;
```

The crux of the matter is that `localStorage` behaves like a javascript object. So, it means you should keep in mind that if you use `.` dot notation to do this, you cannot do it for keys that come from a variable and are determined at runtime. Use square bracket notation `[]` for such a case.

```
var my = 'firstButtonCount';
var second = 'secondButtonCount';

if(something > 10){
localStorage[my] += 1; // Determined dynamically
} else{
localStorage[second] += 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can continue to use dot notation to add new items to your localStorage object. `localStorage.keyName = value` is totally acceptable. To see what it looks like open your browser dev tools and enter `localStorage` in the console. You will see that it is basically just an object.